Spark 3.5.0 java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: JAVA_11
Trying to upgrade my project to use Spark 3.5.0
Facing an issue while maven clean install
All my test involving Spark are failing with below error
An exception or error caused a run to abort: JAVA_11 
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: JAVA_11
    at org.apache.spark.internal.config.UI$.<init>(UI.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.config.UI$.<clinit>(UI.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.SecurityManager.<init>(SecurityManager.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:196)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:284)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:483)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2888)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$2(SparkSession.scala:1099)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:1093)
    at com.intuit.mlp.valkyrie.spark.ABCTest.<init>(ABCTest.scala:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.genSuiteConfig(Runner.scala:1428)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$8(Runner.scala:1236)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:293)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun(Runner.scala:1235)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$24(Runner.scala:1031)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$24$adapted(Runner.scala:1010)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.withClassLoaderAndDispatchReporter(Runner.scala:1506)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter(Runner.scala:1010)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.run(Runner.scala:850)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner.run(Runner.scala)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.runScalaTest2or3(ScalaTestRunner.java:43)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.main(ScalaTestRunner.java:26)

Please suggest some way to debug this issue
I am using java 1.8_421 and scala 2.12.12
Tried excluding commons-lang3 conflicts but did not work.
Tried running app on java 11 but did not work.
Need to fix missing JAVA_11 error

Try depending on commons-lang3 version 3.8 or later.

Did you run a Maven dependency tree to identify version conflicts in the dependencies?

I am also facing this issue, did you find any way to resolve the problem

I could solve this issue by updating commons-lang3 to latest version as suggested above
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.17.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>

